# how to access ajax data within the class methods in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular

I can make a http call to get the response and access the data within the block1. I am not able to use it outside the block1. It says undefined. How do I use the response data outside the block1.

```
this._demoService.get('/app/food.json').subscribe(
data => { //block1
          this.foods = data; 
          console.log(data);
       },

  err => {
    console.log('error '+err.status);
    console.log('success');

},
() => console.log('done loading ')
);
//block2
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to the data right after the `this._demoService.get` block since your data is received asynchronously. I mean latter so when the `get` method return the data isn't there...

Note that Angular2 provides the async pipe to help handle such case. You need to set the observable to the class property instead of the data.

```
this.foods = this._demoService.get('/app/food.json');
```

and in the template you can use:

```
<div *ngFor="let food of foods | async">
  {{food.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior. `block1` is executed when the data from the server arrives which may take some time.

`block2` is executed immediately. At this point the request to the server was not even started.

You need to move the code inside `block1` if you want to execute it after the data arrived.